# SQL LIKE with int

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

Is there anything equivalent to the `LIKE` we use with `varchar` that can be used with `int`?

I want to filter with three `parameters`, two of them are `varchar` so I can use `LIKE` and in case I get an empty string I still can retrieve all records. But how can I achieve similar thing with an `int`

I want to retrieve even if `fkProductTypeID` doesn't exist:
This is my query:

```
select * from Product 
where Code like '%'+ @code +'%' AND  name LIKE '%'+ @name +'%'
AND fkProductTypeID = @ptype
```

I want it to be able to retrieve results even when I supply an ID that doesn't exist. From front-end, if I pass ' ' in `@code`,' ' in `@name` and 0 in `@ptype` I want it to retrieve all records

Comment: You could just cast the int to a varchar before you use it. ie: `DECLARE @strInt varchar(20); SET @strInt = CAST(@intVal AS varchar(20)`

Comment: If you are passing in name and type, you might want to re-evaluate the added value of a partial code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
select * from Product 
where Code like '%'+ @code +'%' AND  name LIKE '%'+ @name +'%'
AND (@ptype IS NULL OR fkProductTypeID = @ptype)
```

if it's in a stored-procedure you should use an `IF ... ELSE`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SP_Name(@ptype int, @code varchar(1000), @name varchar(1000))
AS
BEGIN
    IF @ptype IS NULL
    BEGIN
        select * from Product 
        where Code like '%'+ @code +'%' AND  name LIKE '%'+ @name +'%'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        select * from Product 
        where Code like '%'+ @code +'%' AND  name LIKE '%'+ @name +'%'
        AND fkProductTypeID = @ptype
    END
END
```

Comment: So I have to pass `null` from `front-end` instead of zero?

Comment: @Stackuser: if it is 0 you can use `(@ptype = 0 OR fkProductTypeID = @ptype)`

Comment: Yes works! Just needed to use the logical operators properly! Man why didn't I solve it myself? Anyway thanks

Comment: @Stackuser: i have edited my answer to provide a more efficient version if you actually use a stored-procedure. However, remember to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select *
from Product 
where Code like '%'+ @code +'%' AND  name LIKE '%'+ @name +'%' AND
      (fkProductTypeID = @ptype or @ptype is null);
```

The value `''` doesn't make sense for an integer.  And, don't mix types for comparisons.  Just use `NULL` for this purpose.

Comment: Typo: should be `or @ptype is null`, not `and`.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible in this way

```
 select * from Product 
 where CASE WHEN @code>0 THEN Code ELSE 0 END  like '%'+ @code +'%' 

 AND  name LIKE '%'+ @name +'%'
 AND fkProductTypeID = @ptype
```